# '=' expected @techiediaries/ngx-qrcode/lib/qrcode.component.d.ts, line: 9

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, qr-code

I run **ionic-serve** every thing is OK

but run ionic cordova build android --release

**I receive the following**

```
   
    [13:53:01]  typescript: ...LL/Desktop/full/node_modules/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode/lib/qrcode.component.d.ts, line: 9 
                '=' expected. 
    
           L8:  value: string;
           L9:  version: import("./qrcode.types").NgxQrcodeVersionType;
          L10:  errorCorrectionLevel: import("./qrcode.types").NgxQrcodeErrorCorrectionLevels;
    
    [13:53:01]  typescript: ...LL/Desktop/full/node_modules/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode/lib/qrcode.component.d.ts, line: 10 
                '=' expected.
    
           L9:  version: import("./qrcode.types").NgxQrcodeVersionType;
          L10:  errorCorrectionLevel: import("./qrcode.types").NgxQrcodeErrorCorrectionLevels;
          L11:  margin: number;
```

I installed **@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode** and the problem continues

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mismatch between your version of `TypeScript` and the version of `TypeScript` that the library uses. The version in the library is `"typescript": "~3.8.3"`. What is your version of `TypeScript` in package.json? If it is below this, you will have to upgrade `Ionic` to get newer version of `TypeScript`.